# Product URLs return a 404 error when linked directly from a different store language in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

My magento store has 3 languages. If someone links me a product from the "English" store view for example, and I'm on the "Spanish" store view, that product returns a 404 error.

So far in my investigation I've found [this blog](http://www.panticz.de/magento-404-multilanguage-fix), but I'm currently trying to understand where that code goes. I understand it's in the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php` but I can't figure out where exactly in that file I should add that code snippet.

And I ain't even certain that will solve my problem.

Edit:

Ok, I've found this link: http://freegento.com/doc/db/d5d/_url_2_rewrite_8php-source.html

According to this, my file should have something similar to what I saw in the blog above, unfortunately, the function `loadByRequestPath` on my file is different and it goes like this:

> ```
> /**
>  * Load rewrite information for request
>  * If $path is array - we must load possible records and choose one matching earlier record in array
>  *
>  * @param   mixed $path
>  * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite
>  */
> public function loadByRequestPath($path)
> {
>
>     $this->setId(null);
>     $this->_getResource()->loadByRequestPath($this, $path);
>     $this->_afterLoad();
>     $this->setOrigData();
>     $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was quick! I solved my problem by replacing the `loadByRequestPath` located in the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php` to this:

```
public function loadByRequestPath($path)
     {
         $this->setId(null);

         if (is_array($path)) {
             foreach ($path as $pathInfo) {
                 $this->load($pathInfo, 'request_path');
                    if (!$this->getId() && !isset($_GET['___from_store'])) {
                    $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('default_read');
                    $result = $db->query('select store_id from core_url_rewrite WHERE request_path = "' . $pathInfo . '"');
                    if ($result) {
                        $storeIds = array();
                        if($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            $storeId = $row['store_id'];
                            $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getCode();

                            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                            header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . $pathInfo . "?___store=" . $storeCode);
                            exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         else {
             $this->load($path, 'request_path');
         }
         return $this;
     }
```

Don't forget to make a local copy if you don't want any problems when upgrading Magento.